# python, pyserial to read reply data

Tags: python, pyserial

I write to my device in hexadecimal format using `pyserial`:

```
ser.write("\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x0A\xC5\xCD")
data = ser.readline()
print data
```

The output is:

```
Q,f�    ��
Q.f�    �   
Q8f�    �B
Q5f�    �
```

My problem is how to show the output in hex format, for instance

```
01 03 14 50 AD 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 DC 00 00 00 09 00 00 A8 42
```

Also, how can I convert to decimal:

```
50AD = 20653
66DC = 26332
```

Comment: see http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html for formatting strings. Also, you don't need to 'convert' to decimal, it is only a matter of display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have two problems:

1. The baud rate used by your Python script does not match the baud rate set in you terminal. Try to get them right while sending some printable ASCII values just for testing.
2. If you want to see the data as hex (not as ASCII characters) look if you can change some settings in your terminal.

Comment: That is assuming there is anything wrong with the data. The response actually look quite regular, assuming 16-bit integers are expected from the serial line.

Comment: @Krumelur: even if baud rates don't match the output will very likely look somehow regular, because common baud rate values are powers of two times 300 baud (or at least integer multiples).

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but the question was really about how to format output, I did not see any hint that something was actually wrong with the data.

Answer (score 2):

To view the hex:

```
print ' '.join('%2x' % ord(c) for c in data)
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with viewing decimals. If you're trying to split the data in 16-bit chunks and display them as decimal, then this should do the trick:

```
print [256*ord(c) + ord(d) for c, d in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])]
```

Comment: thanks, problem have been solved. just add data = data.encode('hex'), and for convert just use data[4:6], thanks @grahamstratton and all